# DOMPDFModule won't render fields correctly

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to render a PDF document via the DOMPDFModule for Zend Framework 2. It renders for the most part successfully but the fields are off. Here is my code for both the controller and the view:

```
 public function pdfAction()
 {
    $pdf = new PdfModel();
    $pdf->setOption('filename', 'questions');
    $pdf->setOption('paperSize', 'a3');
    $pdf->setOption('paperOrientation', 'landscape');

    $pdf->setVariables(array(
        'records' => $this->getQuestionsService()->getRecords()
    ));

    return $pdf;
 }
```

and the view -

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://dev.teeforall.com/images/logo.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Questions Report</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td> <!-- 0 -->
                <td>Question</td> <!-- 1 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Order Issue</td> <!-- 2 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Shipping Issue</td> <!-- 3 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Refunds/Returns Issues</td><!-- 4 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Update Issues</td> <!-- 5 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Campaign Issue</td> <!-- 6 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Change Issues</td> <!-- 7 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Design Issues</td> <!-- 8 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">TeeForAll Works</td> <!-- 9 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Order ID</td> <!-- 10 -->
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Site url</td> <!-- 11 -->
                <td>Name</td> <!-- 12 -->
                <td>Email</td> <!-- 13 -->
                <td>Comment</td> <!-- 14 -->
                <td>Status</td> <!-- 15 -->
            </tr>

            <?php 


                if (false !== $this->records) {
                    foreach ($this->records as $records): ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $records->id; ?></td> <!--  0 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->question; ?></td> <!-- 1 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->order_issue; ?></td> <!-- 2 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->sub_shipping_issue; ?></td> <!-- 3 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->sub_refunds_returns_issue; ?></td> <!-- 4 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->sub_update_issue; ?></td> <!-- 5 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->sub_campaign_issue; ?></td> <!-- 6 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->sub_campaign_change_issues; ?></td> <!-- 7 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->sub_campaign_design_changes; ?></td> <!-- 8 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->sub_teeforall_works; ?></td> <!-- 9 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->order_id; ?></td> <!-- 10 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->site_url; ?></td> <!-- 11 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->name; ?></td> <!-- 12 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->email; ?></td> <!-- 13 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->comment; ?></td> <!-- 14 -->
                        <td><?php echo $records->status; ?></td> <!-- 15 -->
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

                <?php } else {  ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>null</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php 
                      }
                ?>
    </table>
```

Here is the actual code grabbing the database entries:

```
 /**
 * Gets all rows from the database table questions
 * @return ResultSet|bool
 */
public function getRecords()
{

    $sql_select = new Select('questions');

    $sql_select->columns(array(
        'id', 'question', 'order_issue', 'sub_shipping_issue', 'sub_refunds_returns_issue', 'sub_update_issue',
        'sub_campaign_issue', 'sub_campaign_change_issues', 'sub_campaign_design_changes', 'sub_teeforall_works', 'order_id', 
        'site_url', 'name', 'email', 'comment', 'status'
    ))->where(new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\IsNotNull('id'));


    $select = $this->table_gateway->selectWith($sql_select);

    if ($select->count() > 0) {
        return $select;
    }

    return false; 

}
```

Also, here is an image that probably best describes what I am trying to say:

[image]

As you can see, the fields are off by one (15 should be in the id field) and so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use directly DOMPDF class in your project.

Comment: It's a module developed to make it easier. see here - https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule

Comment: Probably the issue with data check with print_r( $this->getQuestionsService()->getRecords())

Comment: it's valid, just checked. It renders fine in regular View Models.

Comment: Just raise a issue on their github repository so the builder can give u a track.

Comment: I did, but its been without any updates or comments for about 3 years. Hopefully someone will come across this question and be able to answer it.

Comment: Do you have the same issue without the CSS ? Had a similar behavior with bootstrap a few days ago, turn out it was caused by a :before pseudo element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css` that you call from a view.
To be precise, `*:before, *:after` results in this row shift.

It's a known issue in DOMPDF:

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1103

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/758#issuecomment-86180160

As a temporary solution you can try to add next code below css: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1103#issuecomment-185855083 or use a modified version of bootstrap.min.css. This is an edition you should make:

  `* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
  }
   // DELETE NEXT 6 LINES
  :after,
  :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
  }`

[image]
Once the DOMPDF team has this bug fixed, just be sure you didn't forget that:

> Dompdf is not particularly tolerant to poorly-formed HTML input. To
>   avoid any unexpected rendering issues you should either enable the
>   built-in HTML5 parser at runtime
>   ($dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);) or run your HTML
>   through a HTML validator/cleaner (such as Tidy or the W3C Markup
>   Validation Service).

You might also have concerns with DOMPDFModule though, because it requires 0.6.* version of `dompdf`, however `isHtml5ParserEnabled` is only available in v0.7.0-beta3.
https://github.com/raykolbe/DOMPDFModule/blob/master/composer.json

Answer (score 0):

The code look fine, but mostly pdf library not working so good with CSS.

try to render your pdf with table without css first.

Look if DOMPDF can render it without problem.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td> <!-- 0 -->
            <td>Question</td> <!-- 1 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Order Issue</td> <!-- 2 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Shipping Issue</td> <!-- 3 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Refunds/Returns Issues</td><!-- 4 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Update Issues</td> <!-- 5 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Campaign Issue</td> <!-- 6 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Change Issues</td> <!-- 7 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Design Issues</td> <!-- 8 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">TeeForAll Works</td> <!-- 9 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Order ID</td> <!-- 10 -->
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Site url</td> <!-- 11 -->
            <td>Name</td> <!-- 12 -->
            <td>Email</td> <!-- 13 -->
            <td>Comment</td> <!-- 14 -->
            <td>Status</td> <!-- 15 -->
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Data 0</td> <!-- 0 -->
            <td>Data 1</td> <!-- 1 -->
            <td>Data 2</td> <!-- 2 -->
            <td>Data 3</td> <!-- 3 -->
            <td>Data 4</td><!-- 4 -->
            <td>Data 5</td> <!-- 5 -->
            <td>Data 6</td> <!-- 6 -->
            <td>Data 7</td> <!-- 7 -->
            <td>Data 8</td> <!-- 8 -->
            <td>Data 9</td> <!-- 9 -->
            <td>Data 10</td> <!-- 10 -->
            <td>Data 11</td> <!-- 11 -->
            <td>Data 12</td> <!-- 12 -->
            <td>Data 13</td> <!-- 13 -->
            <td>Data 14</td> <!-- 14 -->
            <td>Data 15</td> <!-- 15 -->
        </tr>

</table>
```